# Nodejs Express router.get('/') in users.js

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I m still trying to learn NodeJs but I came across this path thing I encountered in Express. When I create an app using Express I noticed that in **app.js** I have these lines of code `var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);`

And in **users.js** I already have configured

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

module.exports = router;
```

I don t really understand why is it in users.js `router.get('/')` instead of `router.get('/users')` as it is specified in app.js? Can someone explain a bit what s going on in this case?
As far as I understand in app.js it says whenever someone tries to access the specified route(`'/users'`) lets  say `localhost:3000/users` in the browser, let the file required in users variable handle it.

Comment: /users in app.js is prefix for every route. if your url has /user/add than it find /add route in user.js file. For /user it will search for / route in user.js file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with routes the express app is automatically . Here is an example from the express.js website:

In our router file we have:

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()

// middleware that is specific to this router
router.use(function timeLog (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Time: ', Date.now())
  next()
})
// define the home page route
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Birds home page')
})
// define the about route
router.get('/about', function (req, res) {
  res.send('About birds')
})

module.exports = router
```

Then in our main file were we have our server etc we load in the router:

```
var birds = require('./birds')

// ...

app.use('/birds', birds)
```

These routes in the **router app** are only accessed when there is a request to to `/birds` url. All the routes in the router are now automatically staring with `/birds`

So this code in the express router:

```
// im code in the birds router
router.get('/about', function (req, res) {
  res.send('About birds')
})
```

Is only executed when someone makes a get request to the `/birds/about` url.

More information in [the official express.js docs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would just like to point out what I have learnt today after some frustration, and maybe somebody can elaborate as to why this happens. Anyway, if, like me, you want to use '/users' for all user routes or '/admin' for all administrator routes then, as WillemvanderVeen mentioned above, you need to add the following code to your main app.js file

```
var users = require('./routes/users')

app.use('/users', users)
```

However, one thing which was not mentioned is that the order with which you declare your 'app.use('/users', users)' in **app.js** is important. For example, you would have two route handling files as so:

**/routes/index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => { res.render('index') });
```

**/routes/users.js**

```
const express = require('express'); const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => { res.send('users route') })
```

You would then require them in your main **app.js** file as so:

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const index = require('./routes/index');
const users = require('./routes/users');

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);
```

and you would expect that when you hit the '/users' route that you would receive the `res.send('users route')` page.

This did not work for me, and I struggled to find any solution until recently, which is why I am now commenting to help you.

Instead, I swapped the `app.use()` declarations in `app.js` around like so and it worked:

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const index = require('./routes/index');
const users = require('./routes/users');

app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/', index);
```

Now when I hit '/users' I see the 'users route' message. Hope this helped.

To answer your question though, when you configure the route handler in app.js as users, then you are requiring a router file (./routes/users) to handle all requests from that file and sending them to the URL /users first. So if you do the following:

**/routes/users.js**

```
router.get('/dashboard', (req, res) => { 
    // get user data based on id and render it
    res.render('dashboard') 
});
```

then whenever user is logged in and goes to dashboard, the URL will be /users/dashboard.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. That s a weird behavior. I had them in that order and it works

Comment: The one you posted and you got error on:
app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);

 I dont  have to put users route in front in order to work